# Java Tapestry5 dynamic layout

Tags: java, tapestry

I have a question about Tapestry pages and templates.

A user send request to get a page. I recognize the request comes from mobile or desktop. I want to show a requested page with different layout.

For instance:

If the request comes from mobile device I want to load mobileLayout.tml and pages/mobile/index.tml, that index.tml have t:type="mobilelayout".

If it comes from desktop device I want to load layout.tml and pages/index.tml, that index.tml have t:type="layout".

Example:

Show page pages/index.tml only for Desktop devices.

Show page pages/mobile/index.tml only for Mobile devices.

- Requested page: /index
- Device: Phone
- I want to load mobileLayout and pages/mobile/index.tml
- Requested page: /index
- Device: Desktop
- I want to load layout.tml and pages/index.tml

Basically for mobile devices I want to get content from pages/mobile otherwise from pages/.

Is something like that possible in Tapestry5(5.3.6)?

I have tried something like below, but without success:

LayoutLoader.tml - There I recognise where the request comes from.

```
<t:delegate to="layout" />

<t:block t:id="mobileLayout">
   <t:mobileLayout />     
</t:block>

<t:block t:id="desktopLayout">
   <t:layout />   
</t:block>
```

components/Layout.tml

```
<body t:type="layoutloader">...</body>
```

components/MobileLayout.tml

```
<body t:type="layoutloader">...</body>
```

pages/Index.tml

```
<div t:type="layout">...</div>
```

pages/mobile/Index.tml

```
<div t:type="mobileLayout">...</div>
```

Comment: Here's an interesting thread: http://apache-tapestry-mailing-list-archives.1045711.n5.nabble.com/Supporting-multiple-devices-eg-browser-mobile-TV-td2434796.html

Comment: Thanks for link I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You might find Igor's blog post interesting http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2011/06/24/template-skinning/

Comment: Tapestry 5.3 added support for skinning and themeing; Igor has provided a great description of it. The only trickiness is that you have to supply a couple of shims to explain to Tapestry what the theme and/or skin is for the active request; that information can come from the site address, or be encoded into the URL, or perhaps a cookie ... it's very open-ended, thus the need for your application to provide a shim.